how to display google sign-in prompt in angular
i implemented login with google in my project angular/spring boot, but im facing a problem where i want to show the user the google sign-in prompt if he use a specific route just for the ux sake, the scenario is the following :

user create an account with google (but he can't login yet)
admin activate the new user account
user receive an email saying your account ready to use with a link (that specific link)
after clicking on that link from the email he will be prompted with a google login directly instead of clicking on the google button

but when i trigger that google login prompt i get blocked by the browser, since one of it policy is blocking redirecting pop-ups that being trigged by the code


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initForm();

    console.log(this.route.snapshot.data.returnUrl)
      if(this.route.snapshot.data.returnUrl === '/auth/login-withGoogle'){
        setTimeout(()=>{
            let googleButton = document.getElementById("googleButtonDiv");
            googleButton?.click();
          }
          ,1500)
      }



and this is what happens when i do the following code :

but like i said when clicking on the button manually works fine


The reason why sign in with google is convenient is because users don't need to go to the email and confirm it manually. If they confirmed their email, why sign in with google?

@Andrej sry for not clearing the email matter more, the email is sent after activating the account from the admin. it goes like this following:
user create an account with google but he can't login until the admin activate the account, after activating the account an email sent to the user saying that your account is ready to use

you need to provide a button for the user to click on.  Some browsers will block popups that happen without a user action.  However, you do not need to manage any of the google login stuff.  The user will be prompted if necessary.

@browsermator thanks a lot for your comment, because in some websites i noticed that they automatically prompt the login with google on load and i thought that it was handled by the dev, but you said that google handles it if necessary maybe they check if the website/ page contains the google button then google will prompt that login with google

when you make the call to google's auth.... you can test it by logging out your google account.
